# Is it possible to use the Wordpress CMS to change SCSS variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, sass, content-management-system

I have an upcoming project that involves creating a Wordpress theme that will be able to be reused with minor style changes.

For example, I should be able to select the theme's primary and secondary colours using the ACF hex colour picker which would then be reflected on the front-end to update the look of the website.

*I currently use SASS/Gulp to make style changes locally.*

I have thought about using Javascript to identify data attributes set on the body tag, which would be populated with the fields set within the CMS - but I can't imagine that would be great for page speed etc. as it would be changing the colours of elements on page load...

Any ideas would be appreciated, I am open to all suggestions!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Using SCSS variables won't work easy because they are replaced with the acutal values on compilation. You would have to generate a SCSS stylesheet using PHP before compiling it.

You could define CSS custom properties in a `<style>` tag you print using PHP.

```php
<?php $primaryColor = 'red'; ?>
<?php $secondaryColor = 'blue'; ?>
<style>
    --primary-color: <?php echo $primaryColor; ?>;
    --secondary-color: <?php echo $secondaryColor; ?>;
</style>
```

Then you can use the custom properties in your other CSS.

```css
.container {
    background-color: var(--primary-color);
    color: var(--secondary-color);
}
```

Read more about custom CSS properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this seems viable although it hasn't got full browser support so annot be considered. Your help is much appreciated though!

Comment: @MarkEdwards I see. I added another answer, focused on using SCSS variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use SCSS variables I can think of one way.

You will need to generate a SCSS file using PHP before compiling it.

Let's pretend you got this array from a database:

```php
$variables = [
    'primaryColor' => 'red',
    'secondaryColor => 'blue',
];
```

You can use this data to generate a SCSS file with variables only.

```php
$scss = '';

foreach ($variables as $name => $value) {
    $line = sprintf('$%s: %s;', $name, $value) . PHP_EOL;
    $scss .= $line;
}

file_put_contents('/path/to/scss/directory/_variables.scss', $scss);
```

This will result in this file (`_variables.scss`):

```scss
$primaryColor: red;
$secondaryColor: blue;
```

Now import this file in your main SCSS stylesheet.

```scss
@import 'variables';

.container {
    background-color: $primaryColor;
    color: $secondaryColor;
}
```

Which will result in the following CSS on compilation:

```css
.container {
    background-color: red;
    color: blue;
}
```

The only problem is that you will have to re-compile all SCSS if you change a value. You can use **scssphp** to do this on the fly: https://scssphp.github.io/scssphp/

Answer (score 0):

You could store the selected values in your DB and overwrite your external css with inline styles on the required elements:

```
<div <?php isset($primary) ? print 'style="background-color:' . $primary . ' " ' : '' ?> >
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Paul, much appreciated! That's a good solution although with the amount of elements on the site and the sheer amount of different use-cases for the colour variable I think the code would become extremely messy and unmanageable.